# Error using _redirect function on ubuntu

Tags: zend-framework, ubuntu-12.04, doctrine-1.2, zend-auth

I am developing a system in Zend Framework and I implemented user/rol authentication using Zend_Auth for security and it work receiving user/password information and return the Model User with each user's rol.

In my global layout, I have a big banner that redirect to Home `some/path/default/index/index` and then inside IndexController, I redirect to user's home page that depends of its roles. When I work on Windows I have no problems. But when I work in my Ubuntu, the `_redirect` function of Zend Framework throw a Doctrine's Exception

`Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Connection_Pgsql_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""`

But the error begin in Zend Broker.

I using a Plugin in my Front Controller to know if user can or cannor access to certain page. How can I solve that error?

This is my stack trace:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Connection_Pgsql_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""' in /home/project/library/Doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php:1082 Stack trace: #0 /home/project/library/Doctrine/Doctrine/Connection/Statement.php(269): Doctrine_Connection->rethrowException(Object(PDOException), Object(Doctrine_Connection_Statement)) #1 /home/project/library/Doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php(1006): Doctrine_Connection_Statement->execute(Array) #2 /home/project/library/Doctrine/Doctrine/Query/Abstract.php(976): Doctrine_Connection->execute('SELECT u.usuari...', Array) #3 /home/project/library/Doctrine/Doctrine/Query/Abstract.php(1026): Doctrine_Query_Abstract->_execute(Array) #4 /home/project/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php on line 336`

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems unlikely that this is related to the redirect function itself. What does the stack trace show you?

Comment: I update my post to add my stack trace that you want

Comment: Well, from that I can tell you that the actual error is coming from the `postDispatch` method in one of your controller plugins - do you have any plugins doing stuff with the DB or Doctrine? Your ACL check perhaps?

Comment: I have a Plugin that control the authentication. If user has identity the redirect to its home page, else its goes to login. But I think the problem could be a View Helper that I created that get the Name of the logged user.

Answer (score 0):

Technically most of the the helpers (especially this one) work the same way on any platform. To help you figure out what is the problem I have two suggestions.

Make sure that you are in same environment on both systems. If in one you have APPLICATION_ENV 'developer' and on the other is 'production' this can cause different behavior on the different systems.

The other thing is make sure that you set the environment where you think you are setting it. Some tutorials promote setting the environment in the .htaccess file via the SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV developer (for example) so whatever you set in the public/index.php might be not set at all.

One more think is that the include paths might be preset (before public/index.php) different on both systems.

Hope this helps in the process :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked the first both suggestions that you figured out and they were OK. Maybe the third one could be the problem, tonight i'll going to see that.